# unexpected token - android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, unexpected-token

[image]

I have a problem with my layout text code. Instead of displaying the code I wrote, it shows a bunch of weird symbols like :

"IHDR   0   0   �1

I thought this issue had to do with the file encoding, but I changed the global encoding to UTF-8 and still doesn´t show the code I wrote.

All suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but it will help others:
You need to delete catches folder located in:

```
C:\Users\user\.AndroidStudio3.5\system\caches
```

Make sure android studio is closed before you delete, then after deletion you can launch it and it creates a new catch folder that solves your problem,