# Unexpected tokens in layout file or .xml file

Tags: android, android-studio, gitlab

When I commit to git and get error. But I did not stop at there error and I continue commit and push to gitlab. Then when I open my layout file, I found the weird symbols and wrong code in my layout file. Error I get from android studio is "Unexpected Tokens".

I try the solution below but did not works:
[Android Studio suddenly cannot resolve symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols)

Sample image below:

Error Image 1:
[image]

Error Image 2:
[image]

Please help guys. Thank you.

Comment: Similar problem is here. But did not solve.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53526435/unexpected-token-android-studio

Comment: Your first image showing that your file is corrupted. Check and update it first.

Comment: is it corrupt when try commit git with error? how to update it?

Comment: No, it's not got corrupted because of the commit. I guess you're using Windows 10, because I previously have the same problem problem because of Windows trying to fixing the disk after reboot or crash.

Have you make a previous commit before? You can rollback to previous commit if you have.

Comment: Ya, u r correct. I m using window 10. I did the last commit yesterday. I not sure what I do, but now back to normal already. I made a copy of backup file, then I remove the local and remote branch, but did not work. Then I remove the file, and copy back from backup file, remove .idea and .iml file, import the file again. Then back to normal.

Comment: Great! glad to hear that ;)

Comment: Thanks of your comment.